# TSparticles React render particles only inside component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, particles.js, react-particles-js

I have a React component and I want to render the particles only inside that component. I do not want to use the particles as background to the whole page, but inside only that component (div element), as can be seen on [dogecoin.com](https://dogecoin.com).
However I am having serious troubles doing this.
The code I use is as follows:

```
const Block = () => {
const  particlesContainer= useRef(null);

return (
    <MiddleBlockSection>
       <Particles container= {particlesContainer} options={particlesOptions as ISourceOptions}/>
      <ParticlesContainer ref={particlesContainer} id="particles-js"></ParticlesContainer>
      <Slide direction="up" duration={500}>
      
        <Row justify="center" align="middle">
          <ContentWrapper>
            <Col lg={24} md={24} sm={24} xs={24}>
              <h6>{t(title)}</h6>
            </Col>
          </ContentWrapper>
        </Row>
      </Slide>
    </MiddleBlockSection>
  );}
```

So what I do is that I basically create a ref for the container and try to use it as a ref for particlesjs.

Part of the code where this happens:

```
<Particles container= {particlesContainer}
```

I also tried to put the  component inside , in pseudocode like this:

```
<ParticlesContainer> <Particles/> </ParticlesContainer>
```

But that does not work as well. The particles still render on the background of the whole page and I wanted it to render only inside the container component.

The npm package I am using is [react-tsparticles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tsparticles).

Answer (score 12):

This question was asked in the repository two days ago [here](https://github.com/matteobruni/tsparticles/discussions/2591).

To disable particles full screen feature you just need to disable it in the options like this:

```
{
    fullScreen: { enable: false }
    /* all other options */
}
```

Comment: Someone give this man an award!